# Updating to the latest SDK: 0.9.3

Tags: mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush-ios

I have an issue while updating the SDK to the latest version on iOS

So i did the update from 0.9.3 and spm branch for MarketingCloudSDK.

My question is how can i access the old

```
MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_tearDown()
```

Thanks

Should be something like:

```
SFMCSdk.mp.tearDown
```

P.S.
push has been replaced by mp

Comment: Thank you, Gabriel.  v0.9.3 is a preview release and this will be corrected in the full release.